# How to make Windows 10 pivot/tab headers full width of screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

How can I make the pivot/tabs header have each individual tab be the same width and stretch the full width of the pivot header and not extend off the screen (particularly for mobile)? I have yet to find an example of how to do this.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Here's what I'm trying to achieve.]

Comment: Did you check [UWP Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot)

Comment: Yes, but it didn't have an example of full width of screen pivot tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make the pivot/tabs header have each individual tab be the same width and stretch the full width

This might not be able to implemented by just setting the [style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx) of pivot. But this can be easily implemented by [ViewTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class. We can try to calculate the width of each header item by `actualwidth` of the pivot header and the total header items count. And set the width manually, then the header items will stretch the full width.

Code example like follows:

```
 <Pivot  x:Name="CustomPivot">     
       <Pivot.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
                <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Dark" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                        <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                                        <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                                        <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                                    </Style>
                                    <Style
                                        x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle"
                                        BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}"
                                        TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                    FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualTransition
                                                From="Unselected"
                                                GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33"
                                                To="UnselectedLocked" />
                                            <VisualTransition
                                                From="UnselectedLocked"
                                                GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33"
                                                To="Unselected" />
                                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Duration="0"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                                    To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Duration="0"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                    To="0" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF42424C" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Pivot.Resources>   
     <PivotItem>
         <PivotItem.Header>
             <local:TabHeader Glyph="&#xE719;" Label="item 1" />
         </PivotItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="Content content content" />
     </PivotItem>
     <PivotItem>
         <PivotItem.Header>
             <local:TabHeader Glyph="&#xE721;" Label="item 2" />
         </PivotItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="Content content content" />
     </PivotItem>
     <PivotItem>
         <PivotItem.Header>
             <local:TabHeader Glyph="&#xE723;" Label="item 3" />
         </PivotItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="Content content content" />
     </PivotItem>
 </Pivot>
```

Code behind:

```
 private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
 {
     if (depObj != null)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
         {
             DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
             if (child != null && child is T)
             {
                 yield return (T)child;
             }

             foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
             {
                 yield return childOfChild;
             }
         }
     }
 }

 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     IEnumerable<PivotHeaderPanel> headerpanel = FindVisualChildren<PivotHeaderPanel>(CustomPivot);
     double totalwidth = headerpanel.ElementAt<PivotHeaderPanel>(0).ActualWidth;
     IEnumerable<PivotHeaderItem> items = FindVisualChildren<PivotHeaderItem>(CustomPivot);
     int headitemcount = items.Count();
     for (int i = 0; i < headitemcount; i++)
     {
         items.ElementAt<PivotHeaderItem>(i).Width = totalwidth / headitemcount;
     }
 }
```

For code of the custom user control `TabHeader` please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlPivot/cs/TabHeader.xaml).

And the result:
[image]

Comment: I got it to work, but only when the window is minimized to the area that it takes up the whole width. Is there any style or pivot resource you used to achieve this result?

Comment: @JoeyH, I just add some style about colors setting to help you see the border clearly. The style should not influence the width. I'm not sure what minimized you mean here, in my mind, it means that make the app main window minimized to toolbar.If you mean when you change the windows size the width will not take up whole width please put the above method in [Window.SizeChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.window.sizechanged.aspx). But I still uploaded my style to the reply you can reference.

Comment: I hate to bother you again about this issue, but I tried this again in a new project, but none of the widths of the tabs move over properly. I used the code in the Microsoft Samples Pivot Sample for the project. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. https://i.imgur.com/x7A4rXj.png

Comment: @JoeyH, does the sample has its own style broke this. What's your uwp app target version? Upload the whole project to let me help debug directly.

Comment: The target version is 10586 and here is the project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjzDfXpW-m-skcJR31KsfYdS0ldz0A

Comment: I got it to work when it goes wide, but when you shrink the window size, it doesn't change. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: @JoeyH Congratulations, for windows size change, just use [windows.SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.window.sizechanged.aspx) event. Update the layout inside this event.

Comment: I forgot to tell you I got it to work, it was putting it inside LayoutUpdated as well as SizeChanged. Thank you so much!